# Using array_multisort() and putting empty values last, not first

Tags: php, sorting

I have 4 arrays and use array_multisort to sort them all at the same time relative to one another.
Problem is, in the first array, there can be empty values and I want to put them at the end, not the beginning.

Example : http://codepad.org/V6TjCsS5

Is there a way to:

- Pass a custom function to array_multisort
  or
- Sort the first array with a custom function then use the result order to sort the other arrays
  or
- Use a certain argument with array_multisort to achieve what I want

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately none of the approaches your propose is possible, which means you have to take another step back and look for alternatives. I am assuming you want a normal ascending sort, with the explicit exception that empty elements (which you be "smallest") need to be considered as "largest".

### Option 1: Manually rearrange elements after sorting

Do your `array_multisort` as usual, and then make the modifications you require:

```
// $arr1, $arr2 etc have been sorted with array_multisort
while(reset($arr1) == '') {
    $k = key($arr1);
    unset($arr1[$k]); // remove empty element from beginning of array
    $arr1[$k] = ''; // add it to end of array
    // and now do the same for $arr2
    $v = reset($arr2);
    $k = key($arr2);
    unset($arr2[$k]);
    $arr2[$k] = $v;
    // the same for $arr3, etc
}
```

You can pull out part of the code in a function to make this prettier:

```
function shift_and_push(&$arr) {
    $v = reset($arr);
    $k = key($arr);
    unset($arr[$k]);
    $arr[$k] = $v;
}
```

### Option 2: Condense everything inside one array so you can use `usort`

The idea here is to pull all your arrays into one so you can specify the comparison function by using `usort`:

```
$allArrays = array_map(function() { return func_get_args(); },
                       $array1, $array2 /* , as many arrays as you want */);
```

You can now sort:

```
// writing this as a free function so that it looks presentable
function cmp($row1, $row2) {
    // $row1[0] is the item in your first array, etc
    if($row1[0] == $row2[0]) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if($row1[0] == '') {
        return 1;
    }
    else if($row2[0] == '') {
        return -1;
    }

    return $row1[0] < $row2[0] ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($allArrays, "cmp");
```

At this point you are left with an array, each element (row) of which is an array. The first elements of each are what was originally inside `$array1`, second elements are what was in `$array2`, etc. By placing those elements inside "rows", we have managed to keep the sort order among all your original arrays synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to array_multisort can be the options to the sort. So you could pass `SORT_DESC` if `SORT_ASC` is doing the opposite of what you want.

```
array_multisort($arr, SORT_DESC);
```

For completeness sake, here are the other options `SORT_ASC, SORT_DESC, SORT_REGULAR, SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_STRING`. `SORT_STRING` may be helpful.

Comment: Well, I still need the numbers in ASC order, but with the empty values at the end.

Comment: Ah, in that case, you should go with Jon's answer then.

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually want the empty elements? Just remove them before sorting:

```
foreach($array1 as &$v) {
    if($v==='')
    {
        unset($v);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I need them unfortunately, they're linked to other values in the other arrays.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps track how they're related to the other values, then add them back again after performing the sort?